# Fluent NHibernate Mapping (one to one with conditional)

Tags: nhibernate, orm, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, one-to-one

I'm trying to "clean" a poorly designed database structure (at least in my ORM).

The table structure is something like this:

```
Table: Members
memberID (int PK)
username (varchar)

Table: Addresses
addressID (int PK)
memberID (int, not set as a FK - awesome)
firstName (varchar)
lastName (varchar)
addressLine1 (varchar)
isBillingAddress (bit)
```

So I created 2 classes (entities), one for a customer and one for an address.

```
public class Customer
{
    public virtual int CustomerID { get; set; }
    public virtual string FirstName
    {
        get { return BillingAddress.FirstName; }
        set { BillingAddress.FirstName = value; }
    }
    public virtual string LastName
    {
        get { return BillingAddress.LastName; }
        set { BillingAddress.LastName = value; }
    }
    public virtual Address BillingAddress { get; set; }
    public virtual Address ShippingAddress { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
    public virtual int AddressID { get; set; }
    public virtual string FirstName { get; set; }
    public virtual string LastName { get; set; }
    public virtual string AddressLine1 { get; set; }
    public virtual string AddressLine2 { get; set; }
    public virtual string City { get; set; }
    public virtual string State { get; set; }
    public virtual string PostalCode { get; set; }
}
```

The query to retrieve a customers billing address would be:

```
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM dbo.Address
WHERE isBilling = 1
AND memberID = @memberID
```

There should only 1 billing and shipping address per customer.
So far, my fluent classmap looks like this:

```
public class CustomerMapping : ClassMap<Customer>
{
    public CustomerMapping()
    {
        Table("Members");

        Id(m => m.CustomerID).Column("memberID");
        Map(m => m.BillingAddress);

        HasOne(x => x.BillingAddress).PropertyRef("memberID");
        HasOne(x => x.ShippingAddress).PropertyRef("memberID");
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if I should even be using HasOne... it should be a one to one mapping. How can I get the "where" clause in there (I.E. `WHERE Address.memberID = Members.customerID`) to distinguish between billing and shipping? Also, what about top 1? I know I can maybe use `Join` but I dont see a fluent function to add the where clause.

Modifying the database structure is unfortunately not an option.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want a HasOne(), though it sounds right. HasOne() means that the tables share primary keys. Use References() instead.

Comment: Thanks, I'll use that instead... however, without being able to conditionally reference the addresses it does me no good

Comment: What do you mean by "conditionally reference the addresses"? I don't understand.

Comment: The billing and shipping addresses are stored in the same table and I want to use different classes in my ORM to represent these. In order to do that I need to have the reference join based on the IsBilling bit field.

Comment: If you want them represented by different classes, I would recommend using a subclass mapping with a discriminator on the IsBilling field.